# Create DHCP Server Using VirtualBox's VBoxManage utility

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp

I am creating  a dhcp server using the following command.

> VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname dirtylan --ip 10.6.66.1 --netmask
> 255.255.255.0 --lower-ip=10.6.66.64 --upper-ip=10.6.66.128 --enable

When I list the dhcpservers using the following command

> VBoxManage list dhcpservers

I see it is created as follows.

> NetworkName:    dirtylan Dhcpd IP:       10.6.66.1 LowerIPAddress:
> 10.6.66.64 UpperIPAddress: 10.6.66.128 NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0 Enabled:        Yes Global Configuration:
> minLeaseTime:     default
> defaultLeaseTime: default
> maxLeaseTime:     default
> Forced options:   None
> Suppressed opts.: None
> 1/legacy: 255.255.255.0 Groups:               None Individual Configs:   None

But it does not run. I also can not see it from the virtual machines' network settings and when I try to restart it using the following command

> VBoxManage dhcpserver restart --netname dirtylan

I get the below error.

> VBoxManage.exe: error: not running VBoxManage.exe: error: Details:
> code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component DHCPServerWrap, interface
> IDHCPServer, callee IUnknown VBoxManage.exe: error: Context:
> "Restart()" at line 1063 of file VBoxManageDHCPServer.cpp
> VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to restart server

I want to use this to create an internal network. I realized that it is not running when I manually entered its name "dirtylan" on the network config and the machine didn't get an IP.

I need help to fix this problem.

Kind Regards,
Ferda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the host did the magic for me

Comment: I rebooted even reinstalled virtual box and the machine nothing fixed yet :(

Comment: I also uninstalled and reinstalled guest additions iso file nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to enable the dhcp for the host-only adapter

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig <your Interfacename> --dhcp
```

Afterwards i could start the dhcp with

```
VBoxManage dhcpserver start --ifname <your Interfacename>
```

Finally refresh you network configuration on you guest os.